# User-Specific tables on MySQL

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

i'm starting a project about a social-based application, so i need to track users actions in time. To avoid an Epic-Sized table, i'm thinking about create a table for every single user, and record actions by user. 
I've never heard about links of this type (row to table) and i don't know where to find some documentation about this particular argument.

About this, my boss wants to use Drupal for this project, someone have infos about this kind of structure in particular in drupal?

Comment: I think having an "Epic-Sized" table is not wrong... the problem is storing unnecesary info. I would use a single table with a reference to the user id (uid)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...maybe you should go for some "lower level" solution instead of Drupal. Drupal is CMS and if you make website Drupal's way you won't have freedom defining your tables the way you like. It's more you have one table defining some common (default) content type fields and for any new you add Drupal actually creates new table so you end up with some complex database structure.
Of course you can manually create your tables and use them also manually instead of using drupal's nodes and views and stuff, but then...what's the point of using Drupal?

So, IMHO some framework or even plain PHP would be more suitable for your project.

Comment: Of course you can define your own tables in Drupal! However, you should develop a custom module to get it. It would not be really difficult to create a module which creates a custom table in the database. After that, you could define your own actions and use them with "Rules" module. Drupal supports both high and low level solutions.